# Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python

I am trying to creat an options flow bot for my discord server using quantdata. I keep getting traceback after fetching website to login. The bot does load and connect after giving me the "Traceback" error.

Warning Messages:

```
fetching page
C:\Users\sarga\Desktop\DB-Test\flow-test.py:113: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  _form = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="login"]')
C:\Users\sarga\Desktop\DB-Test\flow-test.py:114: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  _inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="login"]//input')
```

Traceback Error Message:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<refreshThread() done, defined at C:\Users\sarga\Desktop\DB-Test\flow-test.py:98> exception=IndexError('list index out of range')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarga\Desktop\DB-Test\flow-test.py", line 102, in refreshThread
    await fetchPage()
  File "C:\Users\sarga\Desktop\DB-Test\flow-test.py", line 124, in fetchPage
    _form[0].submit()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Line 102

```
await fetchPage()
```

Line 124

```
_form[0].submit()
```

Here is the full code for "refreshThread and fetchPage"

```
async def refreshThread():
    global refreshTime

    while True:
        await fetchPage()
        await asyncio.sleep(refreshTime)

async def fetchPage():
  global console, alreadyFetched, refreshTime, loadTime, qdPw, qdUser, all_flow, flow_check, update_count
  
  # If not logged in
  if (not alreadyFetched):
    driver.get("https://app.quantdata.us/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    print("fetching page")
    _form = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="login"]')
    _inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="login"]//input')
    for input in _inputs:
      n = (input.get_attribute('name'))
      if n == "username":
        input.send_keys(qdUser)
        pass
      elif n == "password":
        input.send_keys(qdPw)
        pass
    print(driver.page_source)
    _form[0].submit()
    alreadyFetched = True
  else:
    driver.refresh()
    print("Page Refreshing " + time.strftime("%I:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
```

Comment: Could you paste the error.

Comment: I thought I had included the error. my apologizes. Adding it now.

Comment: I also added the warning messages I get when first loading the bot. My guess, is it's not sending the login information so there's nothing to submit and errors out?

Comment: Not related to the question, but here is some advice: don't use global variables until you learn when it is ok (it almost never is), don't name your function refreshThread if there are no threads involved.

Comment: The error means `driver.find_elements_by_path` returned nothing.  Have you done some debug prints to prove you are getting what you expect?

Comment: Try printing the value of `_form` before you try to access it's first element with `_form[0]`. It's likely that _form is an empty list. In which case, you need to find out what is happening with `_form = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="login"]')`.

Comment: Zvone. not sure what you mean by "don't name funtions refreshThread if no threads are involved" there's really no difference in naming it refreshThread refreshPage. it's to refresh the fetch. Also Globals are very usually I don't know why you would recommend against using them?

Comment: Time Roberts, I'm fairly new to Python so learning as I go basically. thanks for the advice. I will do some debug prints to see what happens.

Comment: Blair, good Idea and I am pretty sure you are right and _form is an empty list and need to find out what's happening